# How do I go from a collection of images, to a full machine learning dataset, that I can then use for transfer learning (resnet50 etc.)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I'm new to the field of machine learning and just starting to get the hang of it. I was wondering how I can go from an amount of images, to a machine learning dataset. I'm not quite sure on how to store the labels for my data either? A csv format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough description on how the full workflow would look like. I can't give much more detail since your question is not very specific.

## 1. Label your images

There are many tools to label a set of images. You need to find one that fits the deep learning framework you want to use to train your neural network.

I've used [OpenLabeling](https://github.com/Cartucho/OpenLabeling) to label my dataset in the YOLO format. However, this might not be the format you're looking for.

## 2. Find a pre-trained model

If you want to do transfer learning, you need a model (neural network) that has already been trained on another dataset.

## 3. Setup your PC

You need to install everything you need for training the neural network.
I also recommend you to install and use CUDA (use your GPU to train the network instead of your CPU) since it's a lot faster.

## 4. Train your model

Use the transfer learning functinallity of your chosen framework to train your network using the pre-trained model and your labeled images.

Comment: Hi eddex, thanks for your answer. To go into all your steps: 1. The images I have already have clear labels, but I'm currently not sure on how to store them in the best possible way for a neural network to read from there. 2. My goal was to use the ResNet50 trained on the Imagenet dataset. As a first step I wanted to try to use the weights from that dataset and use that on my own data and later on do the whole training from scratch. 3. I'm currently working on Google Colab but later on will switch to a physical server.

Comment: This is basically for my masters thesis and the images are all in a format of 576x576 with 3 channels (RGB). If you need additional information, let me know.

Comment: Maybe this helps to choose how you want to store the label data: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#reading_input_data